# Spark SaveAsTable not allowed - Databricks throws UC not exist

Tags: databricks

I am trying to SaveAsTable a table in a job cluster without UC and I still facing this problem of UC.

```
[UC_NOT_ENABLED] Unity Catalog is not enabled on this cluster error in Databricks cluster
```

My runtime: 11.3

When I use the same command in an interactive cluster, I receive no error. Bellow follow the same function that runs in interactive and not run in ephemeral cluster:

```
def _delta_write(write_mode: str,
             container: str,
             storage_account: str,
             destination_path: str,
             df: DataFrame,
             partition_columns: list,
             TableName: str):
    writer = df.write.format('delta')\
    .option('path',f"abfss://{container}@{storage_account}.dfs.core.windows.net/{destination_path}/data")\
    .mode(write_mode)\
    .partitionBy(partition_columns)\
    .saveAsTable(TableName)
```

I just want to save the table in hive_metastore, the traditional internal metastore from Databricks using a job and I can not activate UC because my account is not premium.

Any Tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ran into the same. Short: 99% your problem is that `TableName` contains 3-level name (catalog.schema.table), where you intended to have schema.table only.